# Find a position in an anonymous List

Tags: c#

Got the following query:

[I simplied the query for this example]

```
var Query = (from U in Users
             select new { ID = U.ID,Name = U.Name, Surname = U.Surname}).ToList();
```

How can I find the second row in Query?

Thanking you all in advance

Comment: Are you honestly telling me you don't know how to index into a list? This is really simple stuff, I suggest you read some material on C# & lists before posting questions like this.

Comment: You're right - I meant getting for example ID of the second Row.

Forms[2].ID - Sorry. Blonde Moment.

Answer (score 0):

Since Query is a list you can use index accessors, which are 0 based.

So, the second row would be:

```
Query[1]
```

Ensure though that the number of records returned is 2 or higher or you will get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a list you can simply do

```
Query[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Users` is an `IQueryable<T>` and you are only interested in the ID of the second row then you can do

```
var id = Users.Skip(1)
              .Take(1)
              .Select(x => x.ID);
```

This will only return the second row ID field from the DB and avoid pulling all the records and filtering in memory.

Alternatively, if `Users` is already an in-memory list (e.g. `List<T>`) then you can simply do

```
var id = Users[1].ID;
```